# js Array index out of bound

Tags: javascript

```
NPC : 
var posArrayx = [-1638, -1496, -1386, -1366, -1286, -1252, -1178, -1040, -908, -884, -678, -578, -584, -438, -318, -200, 300, 560, 618, 784, 778, 894, 1142, 1048, 1234, 1348];
var eim, status = -1;

function start() {
    eim = cm.getPlayer().getEventInstance();
    if (eim != null) {
        action(1, 0, 0);
    } else {
        cm.warp(261000021);
        cm.dispose();
    }
}

function action(m, t, s) {
    if (m < 0) {
        cm.dispose();
        return;
    }
    if (m == 1)
        status++;
    else
        status--;
    if (status < 0) {
        cm.dispose();
        return;
    }
    var randClick = parseInt(eim.getProperty("randClick"));
    var mesosArray = eim.getProperty("mesosArray").split(",");
    var expArray = eim.getProperty("expArray").split(",");
    var clickedSpots = eim.getProperty("clickedSpots").split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < posArrayx.length; i++) {
        if (npc.getPosition().getX() == posArrayx[i]) {
            if (i == randClick) {
                cm.sendOk("Lol its the right one, but it isnt coded yet");
                cm.dispose();
            } else if (clickedSpots[i] > 0) {
                cm.sendOk("Its looks someone already checked this place, i'd better look somewhere else.");
            } else if (expArray.indexOf(posArrayx[i]) >= 0) {
                cm.sendOk("You gained some mesos");
                var meso = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
                cm.gainMeso(meso);
            } else if (mesosArray.indexOf(posArrayx[i]) >= 0) {
                cm.sendOk("You gained some mesos");
                var exp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 1000;
                cm.gainExp(exp);
            } else {
                cm.sendOk("Unable to find anything inside.");
            }
            clickedSpots[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    eim.setProperty("clickedSpots", clickedSpots.toString());
    cm.dispose();
}

Eim : 

var pqtime = 45, eventMaps = [926110000], minPlayers = 3, exitMap = 261000021;
var posArrayx = [-1638, -1496, -1386, -1366, -1286, -1252, -1178, -1040, -908, -884, -678, -578, -584, -438, -318, -200, 300, 560, 618, 784, 778, 894, 1142, 1048, 1234, 1348];

function init() {

}

function setup() {
    var eim = em.newInstance("Romeo and Juliet");
    var randClickSpot = Math.floor((Math.random() * 26) + 0);
    eim.setProperty("randClick", randClickSpot);
    var mesosArray = new Array();
    var expArray = new Array();
    var clickedSpots = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < posArrayx.length; i++) {
        clickedSpots.push(0);
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
        if (i != randClickSpot) {
            if (rand == 4) {
                mesosArray.push(posArrayx[i]);
            } else if (rand == 3) {
                expArray.push(posArrayx[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    eim.setProperty("mesosArray", mesosArray.toString());
    eim.setProperty("expArray", expArray.toString());
    eim.setProperty("clickedSpots", clickedSpots.toString());
    eim.startEventTimer(1000 * 60 * pqtime);
    return eim;
}

function playerEntry(eim, player) {
    var map = eim.getMapInstance(eventMaps[0]);
    player.changeMap(map);
}

function playerDead(eim, player) {
}

function playerRevive(eim, player) {
    var party = eim.getPlayers();// player presses ok on the death pop up.
    if (eim.isLeader(player) || party.size() <= minPlayers) { // Check for party leader
        for (var i = 0; i < party.size(); i++) {
            playerExit(eim, party.get(i));
        }
        eim.dispose();
    } else {
        playerExit(eim, player);
    }
}

function changedMap(eim, player, mapid) {
    var onEvent = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < eventMaps.length; i++) {
        if (mapid == eventMaps[i]) {
            onEvent = true;
        }
    }
    if (!onEvent) {
        removePlayer(eim, player);
    }
}

function playerDisconnected(eim, player) {
    var party = eim.getPlayers();
    if (eim.isLeader(player) || party.size() < minPlayers) {
        var party = eim.getPlayers();
        for (var i = 0; i < party.size(); i++) {
            if (party.get(i).equals(player)) {
                removePlayer(eim, player);
            } else {
                playerExit(eim, party.get(i));
            }
            eim.dispose();
        }
    } else {
        removePlayer(eim, player);
    }
}

function leftParty(eim, player) {
    var party = eim.getPlayers();
    if (party.size() < minPlayers) {
        for (var i = 0; i < party.size(); i++) {
            playerExit(eim, party.get(i));
        }
        eim.dispose();
    } else {
        playerExit(eim, player);
    }
}

function disbandParty(eim) {
    var party = eim.getPlayers();
    for (var i = 0; i < party.size(); i++) {
        playerExit(eim, party.get(i));
    }
    eim.dispose();
}

function playerExit(eim, player) {
    eim.unregisterPlayer(player);
    player.changeMap(exitMap);
}

function removePlayer(eim, player) {
    eim.unregisterPlayer(player);
    player.getMap().removePlayer(player);
    player.setMap(exitMap);
}

function clearPQ(eim) {
    var party = eim.getPlayers();
    for (var i = 0; i < party.size(); i++) {
        playerExit(eim, party.get(i));
    }
    eim.dispose();
}

function allMonstersDead(eim) {
}

function monsterDead(eim) {

}

function monsterValue(eim) {
    return -1;
}

function cancelSchedule() {
}

function scheduledTimeout(eim) {
    if (eim != null) {
        if (eim.getPlayerCount() > 0) {
            var pIter = eim.getPlayers().iterator();
            while (pIter.hasNext()) {
                playerExit(eim, pIter.next());
            }
        }
        eim.dispose();
    }
}

function dispose(eim) {

}

Error : 
Caused by: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorException: Array index 1
5 is out of bounds [0..0]. (<Unknown source>#49)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.DefaultErrorReporter.runtimeError
(Unknown Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.reportRuntimeError(Unknow
n Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.reportRuntimeError(Unknow
n Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Context.reportRuntimeError2(Unkno
wn Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.NativeJavaArray.put(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptableObject.putProperty(Unkn
own Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.setObjectIndex(Unkn
own Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.setObjectIndex(Unkn
own Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Unknown
 Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.Interpreter.interpret(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown
Source)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ContextFactory.doTopCall(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.superDoTopCall(Unknown
Source)
        at com.sun.script.javascript.RhinoScriptEngine$1.doTopCall(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(Unknown S
ource)
        at sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.InterpretedFunction.call(Unknown
Source)
        ... 27 more
```

No matter how am i trying to do it. for somereason i can't change the clickedSpots Array.. it does recognize the array but i can't change the data. i cant push into it. and i can't change the data inside it. Line : 49 is , clickedPos[i] = 1. any one have a solution to this problem ? i'm really desperate. i tried couple of things and none of them are working.

Comment: This seems rather strange, `clickedSpots` is an array, but then you try to call `split(",")` on it.

Comment: You beat me to it @ci_

Comment: @xDaevax except that wouldn't generate the exception presented here, something is odd

Comment: You are correct, my bad. i've eddited the post . the error is the same error,. @ci_

Comment: What is `posArrayx` and where is it defined?

Comment: Can you give us a more complete code sample?  What framework are you using that defines `setProperty` and `getProperty` methods?  Where is eim declared in the top code listing?

Comment: Agreed @xDaevax, I feel like we're missing some key points here that would help in figuring this out.

Comment: I'll just post the full code, One moment please,

Comment: Added the full code, @xDaevax

Comment: Thanks for that.  Still could use a bit more context though.  What is `em`?  What is `cm`?  Are you using some framework?

Comment: Well, im not using framework. about the em and cm. they are classes in my source.

Comment: @BillowXD I'm not even sure you're looking at the right line here, can you debug this step by step and give us some more information what line breaks, what the types of the variables are at that stage and any other parameters?

Comment: @ci_ The error happends when im trying to push new data to the clickedSpots array. for somereason its work properly in the eim script. but not in the npc script.

Comment: Also, you have `var clickedSpots = eim.getProperty("clickedSpots").split(",");` which is an Array, then you push to the array, then you store the **ARRAY** back in the `setProperty` method, but in your setup you store `array.ToString()`  If line "49" is the issue, then it seems like line 52 should be storing `clickedSpots` as a string, rather than an array so it is consistent with your setup method.  Don't know if that is *the* issue, but it is *an* issue.

Comment: setProperty / getProperty works on string stored data. so if i want to store an array i'll have to parse the array to string.

Comment: Seems like you're using ScriptScraft to write a MineCraft mod, is that correct?

Comment: Im taking my word back, nothing work no matter how am i trying to do this method. I'll post the new try method.

Comment: xDaevax. i've posted the other way of doing it. but still nothing works.

Comment: is there a jsfiddle for this? i tried to run `start()` but only got an error that cm is not defined

Comment: @llamerr , cm is not defined because you need the source files. i've just posted a tiny piece of the code. and i don't know whats worng about it.

Comment: what I meant is that you could provide jsfiddle example which everyone can inspect and have same result as you

Comment: We need to see what setProperty and getProperty do.  There may be an underlying implementation detail causing the behavior.  The closest I came to a working fiddle that reproduced a similar issue was: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/eq70awut/